# Supporting multiple versions of Excel for automation from an Access application

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access app, developed in Access 2013 in multi-user env, uses Excel automation to export and format an Excel file.

The normal Office/Excel 2013 (15.0) references have been made and all works well on Office 2013 machines.  Does not play nicely on 2010 machines.

Using a 2010 machine, I replaced the 15.0 references with 14.0 references, and the app is happy on 2010 and 2013 machines.  Upon next edit/update on my 2013 machine the 15.0 references return.

Any suggestions to more conveniently develop/operate in this multi-version environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into using [late binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115)?

Comment: I setup this app using Late-Binding type declarations, but then proceeded to use "xlEdgeTop" type variables, prompting me to add the necessary references.  So, a mixed bag - needs to be fixed using Constants.  Thanks for prompting the evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall solution to this issue is to use [late binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115). The downsides to late binding are

- `Dim xlApp As Object` means that we don't get any IntelliSense for `xlApp`, and
- related constants like `xlEdgeTop` are not defined without the associated Reference

These issues can be mitigated by using conditional compilation in the VBA project. For development, add the required Reference to the project and define a conditional compilation argument

[image: ContextMenu.png]

[image: PropertiesDialog.png]

which you can use in your code like this

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub WorkWithExcel()
    #If LateBinding Then
        Dim xlApp As Object
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    #Else
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    #End If

    Debug.Print xlEdgeTop
End Sub
```

To avoid clutter, I would be inclined to keep the constants in a separate Module like this

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

#If LateBinding Then
    Public Const xlEdgeTop = 8
#End If
```

When the code tweaking is complete, remove the Reference, set the `LateBinding` argument to "True" (`LateBinding = -1`) and compile the project. Add any constants you've missed (there always seems to be one or two) and when it compiles without the Reference you should be good to deploy.

For the next development session, set LateBinding back to "False" (`LateBinding = 0`) and add the Reference back in.

Comment: Thank you Gord great info!  Late Binding is now working perfectly for my 2013 and 2010 users.  Current issue is Access will not permit me to Save As .ACCDE (2010 Runtime) for my Access 2007 users without inserting back the Excel 14.0 Reference.  Very Odd!.

Comment: I'll try the conditional approach you noted - maybe this will permit the .ACCDE to be created.

Comment: Update:  A full and clean late-binding implementation seems to have eliminated the issue I was seeing where I was unable to save-as  *.ACCDE (2010 runtime).