# Access 2013 Word 15 reference not degrading to Word 14 on Access 2010 and Requires Elevation

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access application developed in 2013. When I select the Word 15 object library to open Word documents in my development environment it works fine.

When I put the file on the client's machine, which is running Access and Word 2010, it throws an error saying that it cannot find the Word 15 reference.

If I go in and uncheck the Word 15 reference and check the Word 14 reference, it will start without errors, but when I try to generate a letter in Word 2010 from Access 2010, it throws an error:

> "cmdDraftLetter_Click: -2147024156 Automation error The requested operation requires elevation"

The error only happened on one account on this machine. The Administrator account and two other user accounts did not invoke the error.

I checked the user account level and found it was an Administrator. I checked to make sure that they were actually *in* the Administrators group. None of this solved my issue.

Comment: If you need to support multiple versions of Office then you might want to convert your code to use [late binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115). For an example of how to use conditional compilation to help manage such code see my related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26166965/2144390).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Supporting multiple versions of Excel for automation from an Access application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161442/supporting-multiple-versions-of-excel-for-automation-from-an-access-application)

Comment: As it turns out, I guess I have two separate problems. Your solution works for one, but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Gord's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26166965/2144390) regarding binding solved half my problem. The elevation problem, I solved by going to the Office folder and checking the properties of winword.exe and msaccess.exe.

winword was ticked to "Run as Adminstrator".

msaccess was not.

ticking the "Run as Adminstrator" for msaccess resolved the Elevation problem.